# How to make infinite swipe using cardstackview android in java

Tags: java, android

I want to implement infinite swipe using cardstackview in android studio .

For example, if the user reaches end of the stack the stack should again start from begining.

For example let's say I have 4 stack cards 1,2,3,4.

The user swipes from 1 and goes to 2 then swipes again and goes to 3 and so on on so forth. once the user is at card 4 and he makes a swipe then the next card should be 1 and the user will keep swiping 1,2,3,4 infinitely.

it's mentioned in documentation that it can be achieved by updating list in adapter but i don't know how to do it.

I have tried this code .. but it isn't working

```
 CardStackView view;
 view = findViewById(R.id.card_stack);
 manager = new CardStackLayoutManager(this, new 
 CardStackListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCardDragging(Direction direction, float ratio) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCardSwiped(Direction direction) {
            if(direction == Direction.Bottom){
                load_ads();
                view.rewind();
            } else if (direction == Direction.Top) {
                load_ads();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCardRewound() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCardCanceled() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCardAppeared(View view, int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCardDisappeared(View view, int position) {

        }
    });
    manager.setStackFrom(StackFrom.Bottom);
    manager.setVisibleCount(3);
    manager.setTranslationInterval(8.0f);
    manager.setScaleInterval(0.95f);
    manager.setSwipeThreshold(0.1f);
    manager.setMaxDegree(00.0f);
    manager.setDirections(Direction.VERTICAL);
    manager.setCanScrollHorizontal(false);
    manager.setSwipeableMethod(SwipeableMethod.Manual);
    manager.setOverlayInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```

And my Adapter class code is:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.Viewholder> {

ArrayList<NewsData> news;
Context context;

public NewsAdapter(ArrayList<NewsData> news, Context context) {
    this.news = news;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_item_card,parent,false);
    return new Viewholder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Viewholder holder, int position) {
    holder.setData(news.get(position),context);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return news.size();
}

public static class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ShapeableImageView picture;
    TextView category,title,timestamp,description;
    CardView read_more,category_card,item;
    LinearLayout card;



    public Viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        picture = itemView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
        category = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        timestamp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        read_more = itemView.findViewById(R.id.read_more);
        card = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card);
        category_card = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_card);
        item = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item);



    }

    public void setData(NewsData newsData, Context context) {

        category_card.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_category);
        read_more.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_read_more);

        if(Objects.equals(newsData.getCategory(), "World")){
            card.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_news_item_world);
        }else if(Objects.equals(newsData.getCategory(), "national")){
            card.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_news_item_national);
        }else if(Objects.equals(newsData.getCategory(), "Business")){
            card.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_news_item_business);
        }else if(Objects.equals(newsData.getCategory(), "Politics")){
            card.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_news_item_politics);
        }else if(Objects.equals(newsData.getCategory(), "Entertainment")){
            card.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_news_item_entertainment);
        }else if(Objects.equals(newsData.getCategory(), "Lifestyle")){
            card.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_news_item_lifestyle);
        }else if(Objects.equals(newsData.getCategory(), "Technology")){
            card.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_news_item_technology);
        }


        Glide
                .with(context)
                .load(newsData.getImage())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.image_fill)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(picture);

        category.setText(newsData.getCategory());
        title.setText(newsData.getTitle());
        timestamp.setText(newsData.getTimestamp());
        String des = newsData.getContent().substring(0, 300)+"...";
        description.setText(des);

        read_more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Blog.class);
                intent.putExtra("news_id", newsData.getId());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



    }
}

public ArrayList<NewsData> getNews() {
    return news;
}

public void setNews(ArrayList<NewsData> news) {
    this.news = news;
}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @dominicoder Hi, I have edited my question by providing the code which I am currently using.

Answer (score 0):

**you need to update the list of card items in your adapter when the user swipes to the bottom (last card) !**

**Try this code:**

```
Stack<CardItem> cardItems = new Stack<>(); 
cardItems.push(new CardItem("Card 1")); 
cardItems.push(new CardItem("Card 2")); 
cardItems.push(new CardItem("Card 3")); 
cardItems.push(new CardItem("Card 4"));
    
CardStackLayoutManager manager = new CardStackLayoutManager(this, new CardStackListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCardDragging(Direction direction, float ratio) {
            // Handle card dragging if needed
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCardSwiped(Direction direction) {
            if (direction == Direction.Bottom) {
                cardItems.push(cardItems.pop());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else if (direction == Direction.Top) {
                load_ads();
            }
        }
    
        // Implement other methods as needed 
});
    
CardStackView cardStackView = findViewById(R.id.cardStackView); CardStackAdapter adapter = new CardStackAdapter(new ArrayList<>(cardItems)); cardStackView.setLayoutManager(manager); 
cardStackView.setAdapter(adapter);
```